# CreateJs - distance from left

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, createjs

Here is the graphics:

http://snag.gy/aVFGA.jpg

the big rectangle is canvas element, the small rectangle is the image object in the canvas. I want to find what is the real distance from the left.

values are such from what I see in console:

```
regX: 564.256
regY: 41.4
scaleX: 0.4491319444444445
scaleY: 0.4491319444444445
x: 363.3333333333333
y: 409.77777777777777
```

So as I see x is not real. It somehow relates with regX and scaleX. But I am not finding how it relates. From the image I think the x should be about 100 - 150 px. 
THe bigger the x - the more it is to the right.
But the bigger regX - the more it makes rectangle go to the left.

So if I would just take the difference 564.256 - 363.333 = ~200 - left corner of the rectangle should be in them middle of canvas because canvas is 400px widh. But it is not, so substraction does not help. **So how do I get how many pixels are in real from the left?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by using the `localToGlobal` method (see [here](http://createjs.com/Docs/EaselJS/classes/Stage.html#method_localToGlobal)).

It depends to which object the given attributes belong.

If they belong to the shape and your rectangle inside the image / shape starts at (0,0):

```
var point = shape.localToGlobal(0, 0);
// this will calculate the global point of the shape's local point (0,0)
```

If they belong to the stage:

```
var point = stage.localToGlobal(yourRectObject.x, yourRectObject.y);
// point.x should contain the position on the canvas
```

You should use these methods in general because your method might work for the current situation but will probably break as soon as you scale the stage itself or put the shape in a scaled / positioned container.

Comment: tried this, but it returns x exactly the same as input to that function x

Comment: @SPeed_FANat1c For me it works just fine. Is the shape wrapped in a container? Are those `regX`, `regY`, `scaleX` and `scaleY` the values of the stage or the shape? I assumed that these are stage values. But maybe that's wrong. If they are shape values you could try the `localToGlobal` method on the shape / image. But you would have to do it as follows: `shape.localToGlobal(0,0)` (if the rectangle x coordinate is 0 inside of the image).

Comment: I dont see in the code class container and not familiar with terms of this library, but shape is in stage as I understand. And those values which I posted were shape values, not stage. So now when I use shape.localToGLobal(0,0) it got same as my formula :) thanks

Comment: No problem. I edited the answer and hope that makes it more clear. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I guess I found what by experimenting with values:

distanceFromLeft = x - scaleX * regX;

so getting 109.90793888888885 px

If someone has worked more with this library, they could confirm that its not accidental.